Which files are changed when project goes live using ASP.NET Core with react.js using mongodb hosted on godaddy.com
How to set environment variable for production which files want to make changes to go live project on godaddy.com I am new in ASP.NET Core with react.js also how to set .env file for front end.
const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
    env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:63405';

set target in setproxy.com


Set up the environment variable in the asp.net in web.config file based on your requirement:
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Yourproject.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_URLS" value="http://*:5000" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Build the .net core project using dotnet publish -c Release command.
Set up environment variable for react in .env.production file for production:
REACT_APP_API_URL=https://apiurl

Setup proxy url in package.json file:
"proxy": "http://your-backend-url.com"

Build react app using npm run build.
Upload the build both project files to goDaddy portal.

thank you for your comment I will try your solution
